# Parsing txt file which has delimiters as part of column value using opencsv reader

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a tab delimited text file which I want to parse using openscsv and upload to a database. I used CSVReader() to parse the file. The problem is, some column values have tabs within. For instance, a column ends with a tab, and then it has another tab which is used for separating it from the next column.

I'm having trouble in parsing this file. How do I avoid delimiters which are as part of the value?

[This](http://www.filedropper.com/input_1) is the file I'm trying to parse. Each line has 2 columns and there are 5 rows in total. The first row is the header. However, when I parse it using the following code, I get only 3 rows:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("input.txt"), '\t');
String[] nextLine;
int cnt = 0;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (nextLine != null) {
        cnt++;
        System.out.println("Length of row "+cnt+" = "+nextLine.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
    }
}
```

******** Update ********

Doing a normal readline such as below prints 5 lines:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
int lines = 0;
while(br.readLine() != null){
    lines++;
}
System.out.println(lines);
```

Comment: You can't. Change a delimiter.

Comment: @WeeYou But it looks like it is working. It is able to avoid certain tabs. It just isn't able to identify the end of line on lines 2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

1. Put quotes on your data - here is a modified unit test from CSVReaderTest that shows quotes will work:

   ```
   @Test
   public void testSkippingLinesWithDifferentEscape() throws IOException
   {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(CSVParser.INITIAL_READ_SIZE);
       sb.append("Skip this line?t with tab").append("\n");   // should skip this
       sb.append("And this line too").append("\n");   // and this
       sb.append("a\t'b\tb\tb'\t'c'").append("\n");  // single quoted elements
       CSVReader c = new CSVReader(new StringReader(sb.toString()), '\t', '\'', '?', 2);

       String[] nextLine = c.readNext();

       assertEquals(3, nextLine.length);

       assertEquals("a", nextLine[0]);
       assertEquals("b\tb\tb", nextLine[1]);
       assertEquals("c", nextLine[2]);
   }
   ```

If that does not work please post some of the lines from your input.txt.  When I click on the link it takes me to some website trying to sell me a dropbox clone.

Comment: Thx, will try your solution. I uploaded the file because I didn't want to lose the original formatting. When you click on the link, you'll have an option to "download this file". Clicking on it will download the txt file.

Comment: Got the file!  My apologies but I could not see the download file button admist all the other "download app" buttons :)  I will try and add a unit test to test this out.

Comment: Okay - got a good look at your file.  If you have a field that has a delimiter in it you have to have quotes around it (in your case you set the single quote as the quote character) like the example I posted above.   Otherwise how would the code know what is part of the field and what is a delimiter?